# Finding number of lines touching intersection point in polyline layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, vertices

I am trying to calculate the number of lines touching an intersection point to calculate the number of 3-way, 4-way (etc) intersections within my polyline layer. E. g. when 4 lines are connected to an intersection point, I expect the result to be '4' (etc.).

So what I imagine is the attribute table for the intersection point layer that displays for each point the "type of intersection" or "number of touching lines", so I can afterwards calculate the total number of different intersections.

[image: Polyline layer with intersection points]

What I have tried so far is the "split with lines" tool to make sure, that each line is split by each intersection point.

I added a new attribute to the intersection point layer ('type') and used the following code in the field calculator:

```
aggregate('line_layer', 'count', $id, intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

Unfortunately, the results are either '0', '2', or '4', but only randomly correct.

Do you know a workflow using Python or the available tools in QGIS?

I am using QGIS 3.32.3-Lima.

**UPDATE I**

Using the expression from the answer below I am getting better results, but there are still some miscalculations. As you see in the newly added image, at the "3-way-intersections" (3 lines touching an intersection point) the result is "4". Also, on the lower left side, there is an intersection with 5 connecting lines (result=2) and so on. The labels in the image show the results.
Am I missing something?

[image: calculation results using the expression; wrong results at 3-way-intersections]

**UPDATE II**

I am still working on the issue. My exact workflow looks like this:

1. Create the line layer
2. Create line intersections (Vector --> analysis tools --> line intersections)
3. Split with lines (line layer is split at intersection points)
4. field calculator (active layer is the "Split" line-layer): create "type" integer field using:

array_length(
overlay_touches(
'line_layer',
$geometry
)
)

**Remaining problems:**

1. wrong calculations (see results in the image "0" or "2 / 3")
2. duplicated results (in your sample image there is only one result displayed at one intersection; In my case, the intersections are duplicated after calculation). Am I missing a step in between to avoid duplication?

[image: QGIS project setup - label shows calculated intersections]

Comment: Could you share your data? I think there's some issue with it that I did not take into account for my solution (see my edited answer including a screenshot).

Comment: By the way: What are "2-way intersections"? :)

Comment: What does "Create the line layer" mean in your UPDATE II process description? Do you create a line layer by drawing manually in editing mode? Or do you use a specific processing algorithm to generate the line layer (e.g. out of a larger network) to be used for the next steps?

Comment: In any case: Try "Dissolve" on your created line layer after step 1. Does this lead to a better or even correct result?

Comment: "Create the line layer" means drawing it manually in editing mode. Maybe I am missing some basic step in between? I have tried "Dissolve", but it still doesn't work. Could you maybe share your workflow :) ? I'm also confused why it keeps duplicating the results (maybe I am not picking the correct acitve layer?)

Comment: I added my detailed workflow to the answer. Duplicate point geometries should still give the correct numbers. But if you want to have as many features as there are intersections, run `Delete duplicate geometries` as well, as written in my example workflow. Of course, linking your actual data would be best if you want GIS SE users to help you with your usecase. :)

Comment: Analyzing your screenshot once again I have the strong feeling that the wrong numbers result from vertices that don't have the exact same positions, even though visually they seem to. Using `Snap geometries to layer` between steps 5 and 6 of my workflow might help here.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped! Now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To count the touched split lines for each point, [`overlay_touches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches) can be used in combination with [`array_length()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-length).

The expression for creating the `"type"` integer field then looks like this:

```
array_length(
  overlay_touches(
    'line_layer',
    $geometry
  )
)
```

Here's a screenshot of an example result with correct type counts as expected (no "2" results).

[image: Example output (OSM data)]

To test my workflow with exactly the network data shown in the screenshot, do the following:

1. [Download the network data](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Ey5) (Export --> GeoJSON download) or use other OpenStreetMap sample network data
2. Load all LineString features as vector layer into a new QGIS project (and set project CRS to EPSG:3857 or a local metric one for a "nicer" projection, if you like)
3. Run **Dissolve** on the imported layer
4. Run **Split with lines** on the dissolved layer (as input and as split layers)
5. Run **Line intersections** on the split layer (as input and as intersect layers)
6. Run **Delete duplicate geometries** on the intersections point layer
7. Use **Field calculator** to add the `type` field with the expression as described above, but with `'line_layer'` replaced by your split layer name
8. Select `type` field as label and you should see only numbers >= 3, probably with 3 and 4 quite often, no or few higher numbers, depending on your network structure

Comment: You are right, there should not be any 2-way intersections (I've edited that in the question). Your results look exactly what I am trying to achieve.